# Laravel how to deploy in vercel

Tags: deployment, laravel-8, web-deployment, vercel

I'm trying to deploy Laravel 8 project in Vercel, however, I am constantly facing this error:

> Error: No Output Directory named "dist" found after the Build
> completed. You can configure the Output Directory in your Project
> Settings.

I have followed the steps mentioned [here](https://calebporzio.com/easy-free-serverless-laravel-with-vercel), but unfortunately it showing the same error. Has anyone experienced such problem before?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is change vercel-php version in vercel.json file. Like this  -

```
"api/index.php": { "runtime": "vercel-php@0.6.0" }
```

Also change the output directory to "api".
This is my way which fixed this problem. Hope this helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create the "dist" directory/folder in your project root directory.

Comment: where exactly I should create this folder? and should it be empty folder?

Answer (score 0):

- In your Vercel project settings, go to the "Build & Development
  Settings" section.
- Under the "Build Command" field, enter the command to build your
  Laravel project. This command is typically composer install followed
  by npm install and npm run prod if you are using Laravel Mix. If you
  are not using Laravel Mix, replace the last command with your own
  build command.
- Under the "Output Directory" field, enter the path to the directory
  where your Laravel project is built. This is typically public for
  Laravel projects. Save your build settings.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue you have to set the output directory to "api".

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps

1. create a folder called api
2. Inside the folder, create a file called index.php
3. In the index.php file write the following.

`<?php  require __DIR__ . '/../public/index.php';`

4. In the root directory, create a file called .vercelignore.
5. In the file created, write the following:

   /vendor
6. Create an empty folder named dist
7. Create a file called vercel.json
8. In the file created write the following

{

```
{"version": 2,
"framework": "null",

"functions":{
    "api/index.php": { "runtime": "vercel-php@0.6.0"}
},
"routes": [
    
    {
        "src": "/(.*)",
        "dest": "/api/index.php"
    }
],

"env": {
    "APP_ENV": "production",
    "APP_DEBUG": "true",
    "APP_URL": "https://akos-portfolio.vercel.app",

    "APP_CONFIG_CACHE": "/tmp/config.php",
    "APP_EVENTS_CACHE": "/tmp/events.php",
    "APP_PACKAGES_CACHE": "/tmp/packages.php",
    "APP_ROUTES_CACHE": "/tmp/routes.php",
    "APP_SERVICES_CACHE": "/tmp/services.php",
    "VIEW_COMPILED_PATH": "/tmp",

    "CACHE_DRIVER": "array",
    "LOG_CHANNEL": "stderr",
    "SESSION_DRIVER": "cookie"
}}
```

}

You can now upload your file to vercel.

watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dERa0R2zLqc&t=103s . to understand how it can be done

Answer (score 0):

You would create a new directory `dist` on the root project as below:

```bash
# create the directroy 
mkdir dist

# create a .gitkeep file inside the dist folder
touch dist/.gitkeep

# commit your changes
git add . && git commit -m "dist folder added"

# deploy your app
vercel
```

The purpose of the `.gitkeep` file is to be able to push an empty directory with your git changes, **dist** folder in your case. More of that explained in [this blog post](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/what-is-gitkeep/). Thus you won't need to specify **api**
folder as an output directory in Vercel.